# Create MAPI Service provider

Tags: .net, pinvoke, mapi

I need to create a simple behaving app that will act as default e-mail client. 
As per my current research, I will need to create a Mapi32.dll stub, which will contain some functions, but it look like the stub library must be P/Invoke like.
Do I have any chance to acomplish that in .NET? 
Any option in that direction would be helpful. I really do not want to use Outlook, Thunderbird or such complex client. Everything I need is to submit an e-mail trhu Exchange web service (EWS) from MAPI enabled third party app.

Best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a MAPI provider - Extended MAPI provider is a pluggable provider that Outlook itself can use, such as the PST store provider (MSUPST), Exchange mailbox store/transport/address book (MSEMS), LDAP address book provider, etc. Extended MAPI providers can only be written in C++ or Delphi.

What you need to do is replace mapi32.dll with your own dll that implements the 12 [Simple MAPI functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It will need to be registered in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail`